# support for java.time.Instant serde via jackson JavaTimeModule

Tags: apache-flink

I'd like to support serde of POJO classes that include java.time.Instant member fields. As such, I was happy to find a Jackson module that is designed precisely for this use case:

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8

Unfortunately I am unable to register the JavaTimeModule as follows because it fails to compile given I need to import a flink-shaded jackson2 jar that includes JavaTimeModule but am unable to find it (eg in maven-central):

```java
  private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    .enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS)
    .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

Thoughts?

thx,

- james

Comment: Have you tried https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-shaded-jackson ?

Comment: @ArvidHeise I hadn't ... till now. Not sure why i didn't see that jar. Still, the jar flink-shaded-jackson-2.10.1-10.0.jar doesn't look to include a JavaTimeModule (gradle imported into idea and 'jar tvf flink-shaded-jackson-2.10.1-10.0.jar | grep JavaTimeModule' both fail to resolve).

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear how you currently use jackson. But in general, there is no need to include flink-shaded-jackson in your user jar. In fact, it is heavily discouraged. The whole point of shading is that you can use your own version without class conflicts. So simply add jackson with the respective module to your gradle project and use it as is.

Now if you use any given format/connector of Flink that uses the flink-shaded-jackson, then you need to shade the time module in the same fashion, unfortunately. You can use the [json schema module](https://github.com/apache/flink-shaded/blob/master/flink-shaded-jackson-parent/flink-shaded-jackson-module-jsonSchema-2/pom.xml) as a reference.

Comment: If [jackson-datatype-jsr-310[(https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310) were added to  [json schema module](https://github.com/apache/flink-shaded/blob/master/flink-shaded-jackson-parent/flink-shaded-jackson-module-jsonSchema-2/pom.xml) I suspect JavaTypeModule would be accessible. Per the recommendation I'll include Jackson dependencies directly. thx.

Comment: tested/validated importing jackson directly per the recommendation. thx.